# iOS - Disable viewable down state on tapping on a UIView

Tags: ios5

I have a UIView which holds an underlying UIWebView containing HTML/Javascript. On tapping on the UIView, it take the user to another View. When I tap on the UIView, I notice that it selects the entire viewable area for (<1sec) and then takes the user to the next screen. I would like to make the "selection to viewable area" invisible. It sounds like I need something like "showsTouchWhenHighlighted" set to NO, but there is no such accessor in a UIView.

What are my options here?